# Как мне создать переменную Runnable в лямбда выражениях?

Tags: java, lambda

Хочу создать встроенную переменную Runnable в лямбда выражениях, но код почему то не компилируется. Вот пример кода:

```
public class Module {

    public class Comand {

        Runnable command;
        String help;

        public Comand(Runnable command, String help) {
            this.command = command;
            this.help = help;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Comand hello = new Comand(() -> 
            System.out.println("Hello"), "helloworld");
        }
    }
}
```

Вот сама ошибка компиляции[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где ваш пример кода?

Comment: Изменил вот сверху пример самого когда который пытался сделать

Comment: А какое сообщение об ошибке выдаёт компилятор?

Comment: ну кто скриншотом показывает код? Проверьте без лямды напрямую создать экземпляр `Runnable` и проверьте версию JDK

Comment: Вы не создаете экземпляр `Module`, поэтому компилятор ругается

Comment: Эта строка содержит несколько маркеров
 - Конструктор Module.Comand(() -> {}, String) не определен
 - Недопустимое выражение в качестве оператора
 - Недоступен ни один вмещающий экземпляр типа Module. Необходимо выделить память для 
  вмещающего экземпляра типа Module (например, x.new A(), где x - экземпляр Module).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это потому что внутренние классы не могут объявить статичные декларации (поля, методы, блоки и т.д.). Для того чтобы заработал ваш код вам надо сделать `Comand` класс статичным.

```
public class Module {

    public static class Comand {

        Runnable command;
        String help;

        public Comand(Runnable command, String help) {
            this.command = command;
            this.help = help;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Comand hello = new Comand(() ->
                    System.out.println("Hello"), "helloworld");
        }
    }
}
```

Или даже можете перенести метод `main` во внешний класс `Module`. Так даже лучше.

Вообщем [тут в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) все подробно про вложенных классов описано.

Comment: Все точно сработало! Спасибо вам

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо вынести `main` во внешний класс. И потом создать экземпляр `Module`

```
public class Module {

    public class Comand {

        Runnable command;
        String help;

        public Comand(Runnable command, String help) {
            this.command = command;
            this.help = help;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Module module = new Module();
        Comand hello = module.new Comand(() -> System.out.println("Hello"), "helloworld");
    }
}
```